# how to change color of the selected line in sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I could not find out where I can change the color of the selected line, I have got dark grey highlighted color now, which makes it harder to read the query.
I added the picture just to be clear what I meant by selected line.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences - Code Editor - PLSQL Syntax Colors - Selected Text - Background & Foreground

[image]